# Is it possible to collect info on why an app you created is crashing?

Tags: react-native, debugging

I have developed an Android app using react native.
When I run on simulator its fine, and also when I debug via USB on real device its fine.
However when I publish to Google Play store and download the app as a regular customer it sometimes crashes.
Are there any logs somewhere that I can refer to in order to identify what the issue is?  Or perhaps there is something I can add to code to help identify where/why issue is occuring.

Comment: What you're talking about - collecting metrics from your running code - falls under the category of telemetry.   Take a look at open telemetry project.   I think they have libraries for Android environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use log errors to do so, record the activity of user. When the app crashes, your app can ask the user to send the bug report.

Using that bug report you can understand why your app crashes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  So to confirm.....developer is 100% reliant on the user sending the bug report?

Comment: depends what your app is doing, if the information you collect is not specific to user or user cannot be tracked down based upon that, for example the part when user logs in or starts the app. You do not require any permission for this. Everyone must login. But if information is specific to user, for example the service that user is having from your app, then you should ask user's permission, in that case developer is reliant on user.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use tools like [Sentry](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/react-native/usage/) or [Firebase Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=ios) with an [Error Boundary](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html)
wrapping your app to report errors, allowing you to have a better understanding of the production errors by displaying the full error stack trace and a lot more.